# Using _doc type with elasticsearch-dsl-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch

The doc type for my index in Elasticsearch 6 is `_doc`, [as is recommended](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html). elasticsearch-dsl-py has a default doc type of `doc` however (missing underscore). [This is a known, wont-fix issue.](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/926)

I have a Document type, that I believe I've defined as described in the docs:

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    class Meta:
        doc_type = "_doc"

    class Index:
        name = "myindex"
        doc_type = "_doc"
```

The docs for [Index](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html) indicate:

> doc_type
>
> name of the _type in elasticsearch. Note that you have to define this as well as doc_type in class Meta in order for it to take effect.

This seems to work for get, but when using search, hits are not returned as MyDoc; they're returned as Hit:

```
doc = MyDoc.get(id=id)  # doc is a MyDoc

response = MyDoc.search().query(...).execute() # MyDoc results are not deserialized
```

`MyDoc.Index.doc_type` returns '_doc' as expected, but `MyDoc._index._get_doc_type()` returns 'doc' instead.

How should I configure Document subclasses so that they have the recommended `_doc` document type?